# Story about a murder that leads to an execution; turns out to be suicide

Tags: identification-request

I read an English-language story 15-20 years ago (I do not recall how old it was) about a murder, where the killer got caught and executed. After the execution, a video (I think) was released showing that the first murder was suicide. I believe that both the 'victim' and the 'killer' were terminally ill and decided to show that death penalties are wrong, because you can never be sure. The setting was likely in the US. Any idea what this could be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the plot of the film [The Life Of David Gale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Life_of_David_Gale). I think you are either remembering the film as a written story, or else you read a synopsis, or a novelization.

> In 1995, Gale is a successful intellectual and the head of the philosophy department at the University of Texas at Austin. He is an active member of DeathWatch, an advocacy group campaigning against capital punishment.
> ....
> Constance Harraway, a fellow DeathWatch activist, is a close friend of Gale who consoles him after his life falls apart. However, Harraway is discovered raped and murdered .... The physical evidence at the crime scene points to Gale, who is convicted of rape and murder and is sentenced to death.
> ....
> Wright slips evidence to Bloom that suggests Gale has been framed ....  Bloom pursues this lead until she finds a tape revealing that Harraway, who was suffering from terminal leukemia, had committed an elaborate suicide made to look like murder.
> ....
> She tries to give the tape to the authorities in time to stop the execution. She arrives at the Huntsville Unit just as the warden announces that the execution has been carried out. The tape is subsequently released, causing a media and political uproar over the execution of an innocent man.
> ....
> Later, a videotape labeled "Off the Record" is delivered to Bloom. This tape shows Harraway's suicide and Gale deliberately leaving his fingerprints on the plastic bag in the process. He then looks at the camera and ends the recording, leaving Bloom stunned with the truth that the couple deliberately sacrificed themselves to discredit capital punishment.

Pretty much everything matches what you remember, except for it being a film instead of written.

The time-frame is right. Released 2003, which matches the date you remember.  The victim had terminal leukaemia, as you remember. A videotape proved the innocence of the executed man. Both of them did it deliberately to discredit the death penalty.

A truly awful film on many levels.